# Using a service to define routes in Angular2 and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular

There's no method with the Angular2 router to output all the routes, so what I have done is defined a Service to output the routes like so...

```
export class Route {
        constructor(
            public path: string,
            public component: any
        ) {}
    }

    @Injectable()
    export class RouteService {

        public static getRoots(): Route[] {
            return [
                 { path: '/', component: HomeComponent },
                { path: '/about-me', component: AboutMeComponent },
                { path: '/food', component: FoodComponent },
                { path: '/photos', component: PhotosComponent },
                { path: '/technology', component: TechnologyComponent },
                { path: '/blog', component:BlogComponent }
            ];
        }
    }
```

Now I use this in my `main.ts` like so  `@Routes(RouteService.getRoots())` and everything seems to work, however I would like to use the same service to define a variable so I can loop through the array of routes... like so

```
export class NavigationComponent {

    public routes: Route[];

    constructor(private router:Router, private routeService: RouteService) {

       // just write this to the console for now
       console.log(routeService.getRoots());
    }

    // more code here, etc....
```

However this produces an error in the console `routeService.getRoots is not a function` and my app crashes! What must I do so I can use the service in the `@Routes()` section of my main.ts whilst using the service in other components. I really don't know where I am going wrong as Angular2 is bending my mind right now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the method `getRoots()` is marked as static. If you need it to be static, you have to call it like so: `RouteService.getRoots()`. Otherwise just remove the `static` keyword.

---

**EDIT:**
You don't have an instance of your service in the `@Routes()` section, so you will need a static method there. Since all you do is calling a static method, you also don't need to inject it in the constructor anymore.

Comment: And there is no point in injecting it if the members are static.

Comment: However when I remove the `static`keyword, I then error in the main.ts - `routes_1.RouteService.getRoots is not a function(…)` so I am unable to use the service in the `@Routes()` section of my main.ts

Comment: If you remove the `static` keyword, you have to call the method with your instance `routeService.getRoots()`. But on the other hand, I guess you don't have an instance of the class in the `@Routes()` section.